# How to download a youtube video using ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I download youtube video from the video url like (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zs7xO5P3Az4) using ruby?

Comment: Do you actually need to implement the whole thing in Ruby? If not, simply call the external program `youtube-dl` to do the downloading. (If yes, see the source code of said program and port it to Ruby.)

Comment: Why? It seems unlikely that you'll be able to avoid calling at least C libraries (with any reasonable amount of effort).